# This localhost page can’t be found Asp.Net 6.02

Tags: c#, using, asp.net-core-6.0

[Db Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgcig.png)

[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQXII.png)

```
using FirstApp.DataAccessLayer.Infrastructure.IRepository;
using FirstApp.DataAccessLayer.Infrastructure.Repository;
using FirstApp.DataAccessLayer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add service to the razor pages
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

//Add Service to the Repository
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
// Register Context File
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});



// Idenitity Service
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser> 
().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, 
see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
//pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
pattern: "{area=Clint}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

*but did not work show the error i can't understand
this error show*

[error show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQXII.png)

but did not work show the error i can't understand
this error show
but did not work show the error i can't understand
this error show
but did not work show the error i can't understand
this error show

Comment: I could see that you are having multiple projects in your solution. I would suggest you right-click FirstApp project `located first under solution` and set it as `startup project`. After that try to run the project from the Visual Studio. See whether it helps to get the correct output in the browser.

Comment: Please check the git code https://github.com/Asad-M/FirstApp

Comment: It looks like the pattern you are using in the Program.cs file is incorrect. due to this reason, you are seeing the blank page. You could comment on the highlighted line in this [picture](https://imgur.com/a/wTqEmEH) and uncomment the line above it.